# asp.net application intermittently fetching the old values from updated web.config in IE

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have an MVC4 application hosted on IIS in my local system. The application provides the search capabilities by using various Searchblox API. I have stored the host server value in my web.config. Now while my application is running and I change my host value say from "https://xyz" to "https://abc" in my config then for some places the correct value is fetched but for one call the old "https://xyz" is fetched.

I perform the below steps in sequence:-

1. Hit my application page from IE.
2. App executes successfully.
3. Open Web.config in VS to switch the host value.
4. Save the config file. (Now as per my knowledge this should have restarted the appdomian consisting my app and should have brought the new value)
5. Hit my application again in IE.
6. Watch the internal calls in Fiddler. All API calls are now made to new "https://abc" but one call is made to "https://xyz".

This behavior works fine if I recycle the Apppool containing my application.

Someone, please explain why this might be happening and how can I make sure that my application always pick the new values for every call?

Comment: Based on this information very few people can help you. Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: We need a sample that can reproduce the same issue. If it is very application specific, you can only open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and ask Microsoft support team to help.

Comment: @LexLi I have tried to add some detailed info, pls suggest your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because we were caching the previous host value in order to use it if the new changed host API fails to establish a connection. This was completely app specific.